# Query Ui with Bootstrap overriding browser default tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have been working on this project with bootstrap and Jquery UI.

The template being used is https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html.

Now when I use a tag like `<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" title="Edit">Edit</button>` the browser, instead of showing a default tooltip on hover, shows a bootstrap (a maybe a jQuery UI) tooltip something like this.

[image: ATTACHED IMAGE]

I want the default browser tooltip. How do I get that back?